# getStringExtra() returning NullPointerException

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I am attempting to write a simple application that will open up a new activity when a button is pressed. The user will then be able to enter in some text in a text field, and pressing the `Enter` button should return them to the main activity where the `TextView` should show the text that they entered.

In my main activity class, I start the new activity when the button is pressed like so:

```
private void startExplicitActivation() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
    startActivityForResult(intent, GET_TEXT_REQUEST_CODE);
}
```

I have also defined `onActivityResult()` in my main activity class like so:

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        if (requestCode == GET_TEXT_REQUEST_CODE) {
                mUserTextView.setText(data.getStringExtra("input"));
        }
    }
}
```

where `mUserTextView` is the `TextView` object that I would like to change based on the text entered by the user in the second activity. It has been initialized in the main activity's `onCreate()` method.

In my second activity, I have tried to created a new `Intent` and called `putExtra()` when a button is clicked:

```
private void enterClicked() {
    String input = mEditText.getText().toString();

    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.putExtra("input", input);

    setResult(RESULT_OK);
    finish();
}
```

I have tried debugging this and it is able to get the text from my `mEditText` and assigns it to `input`. In my `Intent` object, it puts the text into `input` appropriately, but when I go back to my main activity, it is giving me an error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
```

which points to this line:

```
mUserTextView.setText(data.getStringExtra("input"));
```

Is this because I used the `finish()` method? I thought it was appropriate to use after I am finished with an activity, but should I have instead done this:

```
private void enterClicked() {
    String input = mEditText.getText().toString();

    Intent intent = new Intent(SecondActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("input", input);

    setResult(RESULT_OK);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

replace

```
setResult(RESULT_OK);
```

with

```
setResult(RESULT_OK,intent);
```

when you want to pass information to caller `Activity`, send back the result through `Intent` and don't start the `Activity` again in `enterClicked()`. Just call `finish()` after `setResult()`. This will invoke the `onActivityResult()` of caller `Activity` where the `Intent data` parameter contains the information you passed...

Answer (score 1):

you have to send back the `intent` from called `Activity` like this :
`setResult(RESULT_OK,intent);`

Answer (score 0):

You missed the intent in set result. add it like this `setResult(RESULT_OK,intent);`